# Read data from another excel workbook using office script

Tags: excel, office-scripts

Is it possible to read data from another closed excel workbook using excel office script?
Thanks
Suji

Comment: If "excel office script" refers to VBA the answer is yes. You can also retrieve data from another workbook using script in other coding languages, including Excel worksheet functions.

Comment: No... I am referring to Excel office sciript.. not VBA.

Comment: what do you want to do? Grab a table?

Comment: Yes grab data from table.

Comment: any updates 2023?

Comment: Same request: I’d like my Office Script to run on two Excel Workbooks at once, one being format and formulas reference, second being data destination. Power Automate is not able to act as bridge for such transfer.

Answer (score 3):

This is only possible through Power Automation at this point. You'll have to run your script in a flow and feed the data from another workbook through a second script.

This article/video explains it all (video is bit grainy -- but you have full code samples here). Let me know if this solves your scenario.

https://github.com/sumurthy/officescripts-projects/tree/main/Event%20Cross%20Reference